# How to set up a Kotlin/Native project so that it places resources alongside the executables?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

My Kotlin/Native project's target is a windows exe file.
I would like to ship a text file (let's call it resource.txt) together with the exe file, the goal being that in the build dir, I would have a directory with the built exe file plus the resource files ( so that all I'd need to do is copy that directory to e.g. C:\Program Files\MySoftware).

On Android, I would place these types of files in the assets dir and they would get bundled in the APK.

Is there something equivalent for Kotlin/Native?
Basically I would like to place the text file alongside Kotlin code ( e.g. in commonMain/resources) 
and then I would like to end up with a build output directory that contains the built exe file as well as the text file.

Is there a standardized way to do this? Or do I need to create my own gradle scripts to bundle my exe + other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by @Dmitri, it's not implemented yet ( see [on youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-29311?_ga=2.19212920.1546927757.1578197640-718281365.1577753667) , or an issue [on github](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/2421) )

I've solved this with a set of gradle tasks:

1. `package`: copies the release binary into a new dir `package`
2. `packageToZip` : makes a zip from the package dir, for convenience.
3. `runPackaged` : executes the binary in the package dir, where the required resource files are present.

---

```
tasks {
    val thePackageTask = register("package", Copy::class) {
        group = "package"
        description = "Copies the release exe and resources into one directory"

        from("$buildDir/processedResources/myprojectname/main") {
            include("**/*")
        }

        from("$buildDir/bin/myprojectname/releaseExecutable") {
            include("**/*")
        }

        into("$buildDir/packaged")
        includeEmptyDirs = false
        dependsOn("myprojectnameProcessResources")
        dependsOn("assemble")
    }

    val zipTask = register<Zip>("packageToZip") {
        group = "package"
        description = "Copies the release exe and resources into one ZIP file."

        archiveFileName.set("packaged.zip")
        destinationDirectory.set(file("$buildDir/packagedZip"))

        from("$buildDir/packaged")

        dependsOn(thePackageTask)
    }
    named("build").get().dependsOn(zipTask.get())

    val runPackaged = register<Exec>("runPackaged") {
        group = "package"
        description = "Run the exe file in the \"packaged\" directory."

        workingDir = File("$buildDir/packaged")

        dependsOn(thePackageTask)
    }
}
```

---

This could probably be improved so that one doesn't have to hardcode the build directory names, and the project names, but this worked for me ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It's tracked to be supported (either Gradle task, or maybe compiler) but not available yet, so a custom Gradle task it has to be
[youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-29311?_ga=2.19212920.1546927757.1578197640-718281365.1577753667)